# objc_getAssociatedObject() is always nil

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a big tableView, and I want to add datePickers in the tableView after the user selects a cell.

I'm using objc_setAssociatedObject() and objc_getAssociatedObject() instead of using so many variables.

My problem is: objc_getAssociatedObject() is always nil in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

This is a sample from my code: (assume the user selected a cell with row = 0)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        var keypath = "datePicker\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"
        println(objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &keypath))
        ...
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let ip = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row+1, inSection: indexPath.section)
    var keypath = "datePicker\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row+1)"

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &keypath, UIDatePicker.alloc(), objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
    insertRowsAtIndexPaths([ip], withRowAnimation: .Top)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to create more than one `UIDatePicker`? And why does your table view controller need direct references to all these date pickers? Why not just use a custom cell class that puts a date picker in its subview hierarchy if necessary, and expose that date picker as a property on the cell? Also, [you shouldn't be calling `alloc` in Swift. You should just say `UIDatePicker()` to create an initialized date picker.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html)

Answer (score 4):

You have two local `keyPath` variables, so naturally their addresses (`&keypath`) are not the same. And it is this address that is being used as the key.

Promote `keyPath` to be a file-level global. Now your code should work.

Comment: I cannot put 'keypath' as global because it is not constant. the code is a part of my real code, which is big. I have modified it to be more clear. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: It can also be a static member of a `struct` (or `class` in Swift 1.2).

Comment: @NateCook could you give me a sample code for testing ?

Comment: @iphoner, it doesn't make sense for the key to not be constant. Only its address is used. Its value is ignored. The key is just a unique number (in the form of a pointer) to distinguish associated objects that you may add to an object from those that other code (the frameworks, third-party libraries, whatever) might add. There should be ***one*** key for your code to get its associated object. If you need dynamism, it should be in the value, not the key. Or take Nate's advice and don't use associated objects at all.

Comment: there are many keys used, and there values are datepicker02, dartepicker24, etc. I need to make the code like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a reason to use `objc_set/getAssociatedObject` here—a `Dictionary<String, UIDatePicker>` should do what you need and is sure to be far less error-prone:

```
var datePickers: [String: UIDatePicker] = [:]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        var keypath = "datePicker\(indexPath.row)"
        println(datePickers[keypath])
        ...
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let ip = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row+1, inSection: indexPath.section)
    var keypath = "datePicker\(indexPath.row+1)"

    datePickers[keyPath] = UIDatePicker()
    insertRowsAtIndexPaths([ip], withRowAnimation: .Top)
}
```

Comment: the 'keypath' name depends on the section and row. It looks like this in my code:  var keypath = "datePicker\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)";       This method simplifies my code because it checks quickly if there is a datePicker in current indexPath, in table delegate functions like cellForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRow, etc

Comment: Sure, that would work fine. I was just using the code from your question, but there's no change in the storage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not working, so I'm changing my code now to add NSIndexPath(s) properties for my tableView and use them to track the available datePickers.

this will solve my problem, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the association key is not remaining consistent.

Here is an example detailing how to construct an association key that is neatly wrapped up and will remain consistent. work on iOS & OSX. (A static string constant works on iOS **but not OSX**)

```
class MyClass : NSObject
{
    static let AssociationKey = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 0)

    var attactedProperty: String?
    {
        get
        {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, MyClass.AssociationKey) as? String
        }
        set
        {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, MyClass.AssociationKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

Since the association uses a raw pointer value; If you where to use `static let AssociationKey = "fred"` then the implicit wrapping of `String` to `UnsafePointer<>` would create a new instance of he wrapper when passed to `objc_getAssociatedObject`. This new instance would have a different pointer value.